# Use an "If this already exists in the API" type statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have an API that I've created. I've (finally) managed to both GET and POST with it. Now I want to check the POST before it gets submitted.

I have a class with properties (is that the right word? I'm still learning the lingo) of `id`, `name`, `city`, `state`, and `country`.

I have a form with a button, and the button has a click event method that looks like this:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    void Add_Site(string n, string ci, string s, string co)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            site a = new site
            {
                name = n,
                city = ci,
                state = s,
                country = co
            };

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/site", a).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.Write("Success");
            }
            else
                Console.Write("Error");
        }
    }

    Add_Site(nameText.Text, cityText.Text, stateText.Text, countryText.Text);
}
```

Now, at this point, it's working as expected. However, I'd like to limit it.

What I want to do is to have it look at the `nameText.Text` value. Before it runs the `POST` statement, I want it to look at the other values in the `GET` of the API and make sure that name doesn't already exist.

While I know that I could probably update the database to make the `name` field unique, I'd rather do it programatically in C#.

Is this something that's possible within my C# code? If so, what function would I use and how would I get it to return the `Site.Name` attribute to compare my `nameText.Text` value?

EDIT: 
Here is the code for the `POST` as requested in one of the comments. Note: This was auto-generated by Visual Studio when I added the controller.

```
    // POST: api/site
    [ResponseType(typeof(site))]
    public IHttpActionResult Postsite(site site)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.site.Add(site);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = site.id }, site);
    }
```

I wouldn't have any idea where to even start with adding an "If the name already exists, throw an error," so some kind of walkthrough is plenty.

Comment: You are thinking it backwards. The client (your webform) should not check whether the value exists or not previous to doing the call. Your web service should be doing that. If you can [edit] your question and add the code for the Action you are using for the POST, we can help you from there

Comment: Does your `GET` endpoint have searching capability?  Can you `GetByName`?  If so then this is relatively easy.  Otherwise this will be more complicated.

Comment: So you want to make a GET call, get all of the existing value, compare your value to the values returned, and only run the POST if the value doesn't exist? That seems like a lot of overhead. Why not just check for existence as part of the POST and return an error code if it exists?

Comment: Also, you should either use synchronous methods, or use async/await. Using `.Result` is a code smell. You *could* use `client.PostAsJsonAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which might be slightly better, but it's better to start thinking asynchronously.

Comment: Side note:  You will have a race condition here.  What if two people are using your site at the same time and click enter fairly close together, and both use the same name?  It is possible for the timing to be such that the second requests `GET` passes (looks unique) before the first request saves but then the second request saves after the first request saves.  Boom, duplicate.

Comment: I do agree with @CamiloTerevinto though that this check should be done in the API.  This kind of check is best done _as close to the database as possible_.  Sometimes, depending on the specific business needs, I will actually check _both_ before I send the post to the api and in the api itself.  Never should you check in _only_ the calling app.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've edited the question to show the POST info from the SiteController.cs file. However, like I mentioned, I'm realllllll new to C#, and wouldn't have the slightest idea where to start with the check, so if you could point me to a walkthrough or something that does something similar, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Before doing `db.site.Add(site);` you should query `db.site` for the name of incoming site object and do `db.site.Add(site);` only if query returns no data. Else you should skip adding the site and return error response with message `Site already exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually determined that I should modify the `POST` as said in the comments. The solution I used ended up in this question: [How to limit POST in web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866397/how-to-limit-post-in-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

Here's code for looking in the database if any sites have the provided name (site.Name):

```
if (db.site.Any(o => o.Name == site.Name))
    return BadRequest("Name already exists.");
```