# How to limit POST in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have the following `POST` code in my SiteController.cs file.

```
// POST: api/site
[ResponseType(typeof(site))]
public IHttpActionResult Postsite(site site)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.site.Add(site);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = site.id }, site);
}
```

I have a web form where I'm using code to `POST` the fields to the Site table in my database.

In the database (and also in my site.cs class), Site has 5 attributes: ID, Name, City, State, and Country. When I use the `POST` form it adds to this table.

What I want to do is check in the `POST` code above if the `Name` attribute of the class already exists with that name in the table/API results. How would I go about making this `POST` method capable of making this check?

I've tried doing something like `if site.name == (???)` and then throw an error, but I'm not sure what would go in the (???) to check the rest of the API's results.

Comment: where is the code for if site.name == (???)

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking. I hadn't the slightest for what to put in that code. Tracy Zhou gave me a solution that worked below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the record exists first

```
if(!db.site.Any(s => s.Name == site.name))
{
    db.site.Add(site);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you like to get the status, here is some sample code:

```
// POST: api/site
public HttpResponseMessage Postsite(site site)
{
       if(!db.site.Any(s => s.Name == site.name))
       {
           db.site.Add(site);
           db.SaveChanges();
           var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, site);
           message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + site.Id.ToString());
           return message;
       }
       else
       {
          return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
       }

}
```

Comment: Can I make this code return some kind of value that my `aspx.cs` page where I'm running the `POST` can look to determine what the aspx page should do depending on whether it posted successfully or not?

Comment: You are welcome. The answer was just edited with status code, let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much!